# Can I use a hub with a low heel inlet for a toilet vent?

Tags: toilet

The drain for the toilet runs to the left between two joists. Can I use 3'x3"x2" PVC DWV 90 degree Hub x Hub elbow with low heel inlet under the toilet and run two-inch pipe to the right of the toilet followed by 90 elbow and two-inch vertical pipe up to the roof?

[image: Proposed pipe configuration with heel inlet mounted horizontally]

Comment: My understanding is that heel inlets can't be used horizontally. You'd use a 3" hub and reduce up higher. We'll let a plumber confirm that, though.